# Webpack require.context module not found

Tags: reactjs, webpack, import, module

I believe it to be some kind of bug but I need to find a workaround.

I am importing images with require context. I removed some of the images from the folder and renamed others. Now webpack is going crazy about being unable to find those images.
Now, to make it clear. I import those images like:

```js
images = importAll(
      require.context('../../assets/webpimages/galleries/studio/business/', true, /\.(webp)$/),
    ) as string[];
```

Therefore it should not matter if the images were removed or renamed or even if the folder is empty.

I found one way to deal with the problem was to change the URL to another folder and then sneakily remove the images from the actual folder, and then reverse the URL.
Sadly when trying another approach of simply shutting down the server and closing VScode it did not work.
Does anyone know a fix to this? It is webpack thinking it needs those images, there must be a way to reset that sort of behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a similar problem I managed to find a solution. It is far from perfect. I still believe there is a better one, but this at least will get rid of the error.

Delete node_modules folder and run npm install to reinstall them.